# asp.net + ImageButton with unwanted border

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a asp.net ImageButton with an unwanted border around it. The BorderStyle has already been set to none. I have also tried Border-Width:0 with no success. I stumbled across this link which:

http://weblogs.asp.net/reganschroder/archive/2008/01/22/remove-border-width-0px-from-asp-image-or-asp-imagebutton.aspx

Apparently it doesn't help either. Can someone assist. Thanks.

```
<div class="squareButtonFrame "><asp:ImageButton ID="imgDelete" runat="server" CssClass="imgButtonImg imgDelete" BorderStyle="none" CommandName="Delete"/></div>

.squareButtonFrame /* This is the square frame which already has a border */
{
    margin-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    display:inline-block; 
    height:32px; 
    width:35px; 
    border: thin solid #E1E1E1; 
    background-color: #FCFCFC;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer
}

.imgButtonImg 
{
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
 } 

.imgDelete 
{
  background: url('/Images/Delete.png')  no-repeat center center;
}
```

Comment: `.imgButtonImg{border:0}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is due to not setting the ImageUrl. I am actually using CSS to set the background.

Answer (score 1):

This should do a trick:

```
.imgButtonImg 
{
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    height: 35px;
    width: 35px;
    border: 0; // note this line
 }
```